# Why don't my discord privileged intents work?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Both the presences intent and the members intent are enabled in discord dev portal. I am using discord.py to make this bot, and I have this code:

```
_intents = discord.Intents(presences = True, members = True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=["m/", "M/", "m.", "M."], status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="Loading...", intents = _intents))
```

I was told this enables both intents. However, the things you can do only if you have these intents are impossible. When I try to get a member's status, it's Unknown. And when I use the jishaku extension, it says both intents are disabled. Why are they still disabled? How do I enable them?

Comment: Try using `discord.Intents.all()`. what you're currently doing is disabling all intents except the members and presences, there are some absolute minimum intents that are required for the bot to function that you have disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
bot = commands.Bot(("prefix"), intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

since intents are one quick way to get user data , you should only enable the `required intents`

```
intents = discord.Intents.defaults()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="prefix"),intents=intents)
```

To get more info on [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#intents) check docs.